# Extra Output None

Tags: python

I'm creating a program that asks the user to guess a random number, here's the code:

```
import random

# Declaração de Variáveis
num = random.randint(0, 10)
presora = int(input(print("Por favor adivinhe um número de 0 a 10: ")))

# Corpo
while presora != num:
    presora = int(input(print("Desculpe você errou, tente de novo: ")))
    vida = -1
    print(vida)
else:
    print("Parabéns, você acertou!")
    quit()
```

but whenever I run it appears none at the end:

Por favor adivinhe um número de 0 a 10:

None

Can someone help me?`

Comment: `print` returns `None`. Your third statement evaluates as  `presora = int(input(None))`. `input` already prints the prompt you pass to it, so the extra call to `print` is superfluous.

Comment: Instead of `input(print(...))` I think you just need `input(...)`

Comment: `input` itself is able to print the prompt message.
For reference, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
presora = int(input(print("Por favor adivinhe um número de 0 a 10: ")))
```

instead, write just

```
presora = int(input("Por favor adivinhe um número de 0 a 10: "))
```

`input` prints the text, there is no need for `print` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!